# Spring Boot Banner - Custom banner not working

Tags: spring-boot

I have read several articles on this and I am able to make this work just fine on my Macbook machine running same version of IntelliJ and Spring Boot.

However, on Windows 10, the custom banner is not showing.

1. Windows 10
2. IntelliJ 2022.2.1 Ultimate Edition
3. spring-boot-starter-parent 2.7.6

****What did I do so far?****

4. Created **banner.txt** in C:\Dev\intelliJUltimateDev\myapi\src\main\resources\banner.txt
5. Added plain text "`MY API`" to **banner.txt** file
6. Run spring boot application

I would expect `MY API` custom banner to show in the console when I run spring boot app, but instead all I see is default Springboot banner.  On my macbook machine, this is all I needed to do to get it working.

I also tried adding a gif image and the setting below:

```
spring.output.ansi.enabled=always
spring.main.banner-mode=console
spring.banner.location=classpath:banner.txt
spring.banner.image.location=classpath:banner.gif
spring.banner.image.height=200
spring.banner.image.width=200
```

, but none of this changes anything.  Still, all I see is juse default Springboot banner:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.7.6)
```

Comment: did you try classpath:/banner.txt?

Comment: Yes, but no difference.  And by the way, there should be no need to provide location of banner file in application.properties from my reading.  It should work just by dropping banner.txt in /src/main/resources/ folder and it does on my Mac machine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it is a Maven project, check if filtering is enabled in pom.xml:

```
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <includes>
                    <include>*.properties</include>
                    <include>*.xml</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
```

You can add *.txt the same way the other file types in the example are:

```
                    <include>*.txt</include>
```

Comment: I was missing the include for *.txt file, thank you

Answer (score 0):

After the maven build it started working for me.